# How to check for error handling using UDF's?

Tags: sql-server

I created an UDF in SQL Server but I want to check for null or invalid values. For example If Inserted an ID '333sd' I want my UDF to return a error message or print a message but in accordance to the documentation I have read the `THROW` or `CATCH` and `TRY` block cannot be used.

```
if object_id('dbo.fnDiscountPrice') is not null
    drop function dbo.fnDiscountPrice;
go

create function fnDiscountPrice(@ItemID int)
returns money
as
begin
   return (select sum(ItemPrice - DiscountAmount) as DiscountPrice 
           from OrderItems
           where ItemID = @ItemID)
end
go
```

I have tried to declare a new variable and set it to 0  if It's null but If did it that way I will not express specifically the error. I want to be specific with that.

Comment: Functions cannot do that. But you'll find it impossible to pass `333sd` to this function in any case, as the conversion will fail. If `ItemID` in your table is a `CHAR` type, then the problem lies there, not with your function -- either fix the type there, or use `ItemID = CONVERT(..CHAR(...), @ItemID)` in the function to perform the join (and then no results will be returned). If you absolutely need error logic, a stored procedure is the only way.

Comment: You can't use `THROW` (or `PRINT`) inside a UDF T-SQL function. These are known as "side-effecting operators", which are *not* allowed.

Comment: Uhm... I understand,  I think that I will declare a new variable and I will set it to 0  if  the input is NULL or does not exist  as I have done previously, thanks so much for the clarification!

Comment: Side note: I strongly recommend switching to an inline table value function (iTVF); it will be much more performant.

Comment: Also `money` has serious rounding problems, consider using `decimal` instead

Comment: It does not really matter as all values have 2 decimal places.